# solve the separable equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-2y}{x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need a quick refresher. Suppose I have the following separable equation

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-2y}{x}$

Then I have

$\frac{dy}{-2y}=\frac{dx}{x}$

Integrating both sides I have

$\frac{-1}{2} \ln y = \ln x +C $

Using log laws, I have

$ \ln y^{\frac{-1}{2}} = \ln x +C $

Then taking the exponential I have

$ e^{\ln y^{\frac{-1}{2}}} = e^{\ln x +C }$

$ e^{\ln y^{\frac{-1}{2}}} = e^{\ln x}e^{C} $

$y^{\frac{-1}{2}} = xe^{C}$

I want the C to be by itself, so would the final answer look like this

$\frac{y^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{x} = e^{C}$

$y^{\frac{-1}{2}}x^{-1}=e^{C}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $C$ is a constant, $e^{C}$ is a constant as well, and we can call it $C_2$. So you have $$y^{-1/2}x^{-1} = C_2 \Leftrightarrow y^{-1/2} = C_2x \Leftrightarrow y^{1/2} = \dfrac{1}{C_2 x} \Leftrightarrow y = \left(\dfrac{1}{C_2x}\right)^{2}$$
and $\left(\dfrac{1}{C_2}\right)^{2} = D$ is a constant, so that $y = \dfrac{D}{x^2}$.

**Edit**: Sorry, I misinterpreted what you asked for. Your last equation is fine in your original question - take $\ln$ of both sides, so that you have 
$$\begin{align}
&\ln(y^{-1/2}x^{-1}) = \ln\left(e^{C}\right) = C \\
\Leftrightarrow &\ln(y^{-1/2})+\ln(x^{-1}) = C\text{.}
\end{align}$$

Comment: What if I want it in implicit form? I need that. I  need something = C. Edit. Can I multiply the exponents by -2 to get rid of the ugly fraction and negatives? Like $yx^2 = C$ ? @Clarinetist

Comment: See edit in answer.

Comment: and that would just leave me with $y^{\frac{-1}{2}}x^{-1}=C$...one more question... is it possible to mulitply the exponents by -2 to get rid of the fraction and the negative signs? @Clarinetist